# Modify cake association result array

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, associations, cakephp-2.0

I am in a problem of modifying the cake association hierarchy,I am new to cakephp ,  below is the snippet of code.

**Current Code**

`$this->Cateogory->find('all');`

The output of the above expression is of the below form :

```
    [
      {
        "Category": {
          "id": "37",
          "title": "Inner Title",
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "phone-number": ""
        },
        "CategoryHas": [],
        "PhoneNumberhas": []
      }
    ]
```

**Requirement :-**

I am creating API for third party consumption , now the third party has given the output format as below. I want the the output to be of below form.

```
    [
      {
        "Category": {
          "id": "37",
          "title": "Inner Title",
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "phone-number": "",
          "CategoryHas": [],
          "PhoneNumberhas": []
        }
      }
    ]
```

I am searching on this problem for past 1 day and I consider that I need to make a custom PHP function to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance :

Comment: plz, don't down vote without comment !!

Comment: Well I am creating API for 3rd party to use, and they have specified the response format. Therefore looking for cake way to get that format

Comment: @sanjeev I'd update your question to state the reason for wanting the structure changing so that it is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

### Just use a loop

To convert the array of the first format to an array of the second format - just use a loop e.g.:

```
foreach ($stuff as &$row) {
        $row['Category']['CategoryHas'] = $row['CategoryHas'];
        $row['Category']['PhoneNumberhas'] = $row['PhoneNumberhas'];
        unset($row['CategoryHas'], $row['PhoneNumberhas']);
}
```

This would be appropriate to put in your controller if it's only needed in one place.

If you always, always want your results in that format, use an afterFind method (or a behavior) to implement the same logic:

```
// In the category model
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    foreach ($results as &$row) {
        if (isset($row['CategoryHas'])) {
            $row['Category']['CategoryHas'] = $row['CategoryHas'];
        }
        if (isset($row['PhoneNumberhas'])) {
            $row['Category']['PhoneNumberhas'] = $row['PhoneNumberhas'];
        }
        unset($row['CategoryHas'], $row['PhoneNumberhas']);
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Be wary of choosing this option - it means that your models act unconventionally, potentially meaning plugins don't work and other developers (or you, tomorrow) are confused by the way the models act.

Comment: This solution will alter the result set *every time*, even when not needed and will change the structure of the data even internally, not just for the outside API. Also not using the alias will make this break when using the model through associations.

Comment: @burzum great to see you read the answer (you seem to have completely skipped all the words).

Answer (score -1):

Your association names are pretty strange. Why are they not better named? You can use proper names internally and reformat it when sending it.

If this is just about getting the API response into a silly format that doesn't provide additional benefit use JSON views and change the structure of the array in the view as needed. [This section of the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) explains it in detail, read it. Example taken from the book:

```
// Controller code
class CategoriesController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        // ... get the categories
        $this->set(compact('categories'));
    }
}

// View code - app/View/Posts/json/index.ctp
foreach ($categories &$row) {
    if (isset($row['CategoryHas'])) {
        $row['Category']['CategoryHas'] = $row['CategoryHas'];
    }
    if (isset($row['PhoneNumberhas'])) {
        $row['Category']['PhoneNumberhas'] = $row['PhoneNumberhas'];
    }
    unset($row['CategoryHas'], $row['PhoneNumberhas']);
}
echo json_encode(compact('categories'));
```

I would convince the client and bring some arguments for a proper response format and structure. Most clients usually don't know what they want. Sometimes you have smart asses who think they need something specific but can explain why. Check [JSend](https://labs.omniti.com/labs/jsend) or http://jsonapi.org/ on how  to implement a proper API response format. Understand the reasons for these formats and bring these arguments to the client.

Comment: And I've got downvoted for what reason...? The solution is IMHO even better than AD7six one, which will alter the result set every time, even when not needed and will change the structure of the data even internally, not just for the outside API. Plus I'm giving some extra information about how to build a proper API response format.

Comment: I downvoted your answer for being overly condescending/aggressive - I'm tired of commenting over the years to tell you about this, as you don't seem to listen/learn. Strangely **your answer now includes a copy of mine**, with the same (debatable) flaw that you commented on my answer. It's unnecessary to put isset calls in code where you can assume the keys exist, which they would in a specific view template.

Comment: It's not a copy, I just added the part of the data transformation from your answer and put it in the IMHO right place and changed the example *from the cakephp book* to match what he has. It's non the less a completely different answer and approach. Feel free to discuss my reasons for putting it in a json view. His main problem seems to be to change the structure of the array and it looks like he wants copy and paste ready code as well. And if you don't like me, just ignore me, thanks. :)